# SSL certificates installation raises XMLHttpRequest cannot load exception

Tags: ssl, xmlhttprequest, ssl-certificate, sni

**The problem:**

I have 2 websites that have the same IP address (a domain and a subdomain), and I have an SSL certificate for each of them. The domain is a word-press site while the sub domain is a ruby on rails application. the subdomain has the certificate installed and works with no problems, but when I try to add the second certificate for the main domain, it works, but it prevents access to the subdomain.

In the web browser inspection page it shows this error :

“XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://giladparking.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-slimstat/wp-slimstat-js.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://monthly.giladparking.com' is therefore not allowed access.”

**What I have tried:**

I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04) to allow for SNI support and it seems to work except for the previously mentioned issue.

I have taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) as well which explains that you can't make XMLHTTPRequests across domains. but this issue only arises when both certificates are in effect.

Answer (score 0):

> “XMLHttpRequest cannot load `https://giladparking.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-slimstat/wp-slimstat-js.php`....

The certificate for this sites is valid for monthly.giladparking.com and www.monthly.giladparking.com but not for giladparking.com. That's why any access to this site will fail with a certificate error. This problem is not restricted to XMLHTTPRequests.